# How to delete thread object from device after finishing the task?

Tags: python, multithreading, object, memory-leaks

How can I delete thread object after finishing the job?
Here's the code for creating the threads, also see that number of threads created reach 100 thread *look at the image*, how to delete them?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    segmentationProcess = SegmentationProcess()
    data = segmentationProcess.readDoc("./IT resumes as text/ktalzoubi.txt")
    data = segmentationProcess.preProcess(data)
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    thread1 = ThreadWithLogAndControls(target=segmentationProcess.searchWorkExperience, args=(data, "W", lock))
    thread2 = ThreadWithLogAndControls(target=segmentationProcess.searchEducation, args=(data, "E", lock))
    thread3 = ThreadWithLogAndControls(target=segmentationProcess.serchSkills, args=(data, "S", lock))
    thread4 = ThreadWithLogAndControls(target=segmentationProcess.searchOthers, args=(data, "O", lock))
    wr1 = weakref.ref(thread1)
    wr2 = weakref.ref(thread2)
    wr3 = weakref.ref(thread3)
    wr4 = weakref.ref(thread4)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()
    thread4.start()
    print(wr1())
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
    thread3.join()
    thread4.join()
    del thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4
    print(wr1())
```

[image]

Comment: This is hardly a [mre] - it isn't clear what threading library you are using so it's likely impossible to give you specific help. One option would be to look at using a "pool" to assign tasks to threads. I wonder if you're just misunderstanding the printout though, and you're not actually creating hundreds of threads

Comment: Am using nbmultitask library:
https://github.com/micahscopes/nbmultitask

Comment: Maybe `segmentationProcess` creates hundreds of threads while loading the data? Also remember that `del` doesn't destroy an object - it only removes a reference to it. Since references could be stored elsewhere you can never really control when an object is destroyed.

Comment: Ok, then how can I permanently delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're worrying about a non-issue. The text "thread-103" does not mean that there are currently 103 threads. Instead it suggests that >=103 threads have been created. It comes from [the Python threading module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/289cf0fbf78c4f38c38ac71ac8b772be7ec2672f/Lib/threading.py#L795): if a name isn't supplied for the new thread then it defaults to one like `Thread-<number>`. `<number>` only ever goes up, and never goes down even when threads are destroyed (it also doesn't go up if a thread is created with a name, hence the number displayed is only a lower bound). This is only intended to give each thread a recognisable name, and not for anything else.

These threads are probably created in the lines:

```
data = segmentationProcess.readDoc("./IT resumes as text/ktalzoubi.txt")
data = segmentationProcess.preProcess(data)
```

We obviously don't know what's in these functions. The threads are probably being cleaned up correctly, but since you don't provide a [mininal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's impossible to provide any further detail.

---

There's a secondary point: the point at which Python objects are destroyed are called is pretty unreliable. `del` does not do so - it only breaks an individual reference to an object. It's likely that there are some circular references to the object stored in `thread1` and so it still exists even after the `thread1` variable is `del`ed. These circular references are not a problem since they will be caught when the Python garbage collector is run (but exactly when that happens is a arbitrary).

Therefore, resources (other than memory) should not rely on object destruction to free them. The standard Python idiom is to use a `with` block, or `try: ...; finally:`. However, in the case of multithreading the resources you should be caring about are released when the thread finishes, so (again) a non-issue. (Or at least an issue out of your control).

---

Finally you look to be mixing `multiprocessing.Lock` with `threading`. These are two *different* methods of parallelising Python code and I would not assume that it's valid to mix them (it might be, it might not be, but it gives the impression that you haven't really understood what you're doing).

Comment: Thenk you so much for your highly benefits answer, I understood what you mean. But the idea of lock is that each thread perform specific task, and after each one finish it will go to another thread to update a list, all of them will access that thread, so when a single thread access it, a a lock will aquire, then the another etc... Kindly my bro, am facing another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941098/why-threads-stopped-in-heroku

Comment: About the lock: I was suggesting you use the lock in `threading` instead of the one in `multiprocessing`. The problem is (possibly) with mixing the modules, not having a lock.