# Why threads stopped in heroku?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, heroku

I have been uploaded my project in heroku, and my script create 4 threads, each thread perform specific task, but sometimes log file tells me that some threads stopped like this, (Thread 13)!
[image]

How can I solve it?
this is the code!

```
      segmentationProcess = SegmentationProcess()
      dataList = request.body.decode("utf-8").split(',')
      data = segmentationProcess.preProcess(dataList)
      lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
      thread1 = ThreadWithLogAndControls(target=segmentationProcess.searchWorkExperience, args=(data, "W", manager.result, lock))
      thread2 = ThreadWithLogAndControls(target=segmentationProcess.searchEducation, args=(data, "E", manager.result, lock))
      thread3 = ThreadWithLogAndControls(target=segmentationProcess.serchSkills, args=(data, "S", manager.result, lock))
      thread4 = ThreadWithLogAndControls(target=segmentationProcess.searchOthers, args=(data, "O", manager.result, lock))
      thread1.start()
      thread2.start()
      thread3.start()
      thread4.start()
      thread1.join()
      thread2.join()
      thread3.join()
      thread4.join()
```

Am using nbmultitask library for creating threads, it's like multiprocessing. https://github.com/micahscopes/nbmultitask

Comment: Can I make a small correction: `nbmultitask` wraps either `threading` (`ThreadWithLogAndControls`) or `multiprocessing` (`ProcessWithLogAndControls`). You're using `threading` internally. The two libraries behave slightly differently internally (which may be important for your question, maybe?). I'm not sure I know the answer to the overall issue though

Comment: My best guess is that whatever is in "Thread-13" simply finishes really quickly

Comment: But the result of that thread "which stopped" does not appear!